# How to add "$" in a Integer Field in Django in admin interface?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    '''
        Category for tasks
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    budget = models.IntegerField(help_text="Amount in US dollar ($)")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Data entry is fine. But when I show the attribute budget in admin interface like this:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'budget')
```

Instead of showing `100` I want to show `$100`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `DecimalField` for currency values not an integer field (otherwise you can't have a budget such as 150.40)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    budget = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

    class Meta:
        verbose_number_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)  # always return unicode from __unicode__

    # This method will be used in the admin display
    def budget_display(self):
        # Normally, you would return this:
        # return '${0:1.2f}'.format(self.budget)
        # but a decimal field will display itself correctly
        # so we can just do this:
        return '${0}'.format(self.budget)
    budget_display.short_description = 'Budget'
```

You can use any callable in the `list_display`, so instead of displaying the field, we call the function to return the correct format that we want.

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'budget_display')
```

---

> Can you please explain what do you mean by ${0: 1.2f}

This is the new [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> i = 123.45678
>>> '{0}'.format(i)
'123.45678'
>>> '{0:1.2f}'.format(i)
'123.46'
```

This `{}` is a placeholder for whatever you will pass to format. I put a `0` in there to denote that I want the first argument to go there:

```
>>> '{0} {1}'.format('a', 'b')
'a b'
>>> '{1} {0}'.format('a', 'b')
'b a'
```

The `:` in `{0:` is the start of the [format specification](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), which allows control of how things are displayed:

```
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(123.456)
'123.46'
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(123.456)
'123.456'
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(.456)
'0.456'
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `${0: 1.2f}`

Comment: Also Does `max_digits` count number after decimal?

Comment: Yes, max_digits includes the number after the decimal. So max of 5 means you can store numbers up to 999.99